# What could cause JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken to throw "IDX10503: Signature validation failed." when the key is valid?

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

I have an ASP.NET core 2.2 application that exposes an API endpoint. That endpoint is protected with a simple JWT token that only cares about the subject, the expiration and the signature (SHA256 using a shared secret).

When I call the endpoint from a .net core client, it works fine.

I'm now trying to call the same code from a Delphi client but the server is rejecting these tokens and I can't figure out why: both tokens looks identical to me and they both pass the validation test at jwt.io

**Server-side token validation code:**

```
    private static TokenValidationParameters GetValidationParameters(byte[] key)
    {
        return new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            LifetimeValidator = (DateTime? notBefore, DateTime? expires, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters) =>
            {
                // Cutom validity validation
                DateTime current = DateTime.UtcNow; // get a single value for "now"
                // check if the token expiration is valid and if it doesn't expire 
                bool value = (expires.HasValue) && (notBefore.HasValue) && // both "expires" and "notBefore" must be set
                              (expires >= current) && // "expires" must not be in the past
                              (expires <= current.AddMinutes(5)) && // "expires" must not be any further than 5 minutes in the future
                              (notBefore <= current); // notBefore must be in the past or present
                return value;
            },
            RequireExpirationTime = true, 
            // the token has no audience or issuer so ignore these
            ValidateAudience = false, 
            ValidateIssuer = false,   
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key)
        };
    }

    private bool ValidateToken(string authToken, byte[] key)
    {
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var validationParameters = GetValidationParameters(key);

        // This will raise an exception if the security token is invalid
        try
        {
            tokenHandler.ValidateToken(authToken, validationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken);
        }
        catch (SecurityTokenException e) // this will happen if the token is properly formated but invalid (signature, validity)
        {
            logger.LogInformation("Invalid token received: {1}", e.Message);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The error occures on the `tokenHandler.ValidateToken` call. The token expiration validation code is never called.

**sample tokens**

From a C# application (passes validation):

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI2NjM2MDQ1My1CMDJCLUU5MTEtODM5Qy1BMEE4Q0QzQUNCRjgiLCJuYmYiOjE1NTg2MTMzOTQsImV4cCI6MTU1ODYxMzY5NCwiaWF0IjoxNTU4NjEzMzk0fQ.nso4xnllNc-rXfn5riOWv5fZjNeJMgoQbyXeOltDYb0
```

From my Delphi application (fails):

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI2NjM2MDQ1My1CMDJCLUU5MTEtODM5Qy1BMEE4Q0QzQUNCRjgiLCJpYXQiOjE1NTg2MTYxNTgsIm5iZiI6MTU1ODYxNjE1OCwiZXhwIjoxNTU4NjE2NDU4fQ.vB_gotDk1JGiiDWPT0t6TR471Av4r-LXSgc3zab7EaU
```

Reported error:

```
IDX10503: Signature validation failed. Keys tried: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey , KeyId: 
'.
Exceptions caught:
 ''.
token: '{"typ":"JWT","alg":"HS256"}.{"sub":"66360453-B02B-E911-839C-A0A8CD3ACBF8","iat":1558616158,"nbf":1558616158,"exp":1558616458}'.
```

Both tokens are protected with the same shared secret (b64 encoded):

```
NdFCOQReqUk0mxTqI7psd9JrVjgE7bdPVfjILEa4dzE=
```

(All this data is from a local test application so no secret was hurt producing this question)

Comment: What if you add `ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false` or `RequireSignedTokens = false`?

In addition, for debugging purposes, you can set `IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;`

Comment: @Ofiris Neither ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false nor RequireSignedTokens = false changes anything. i have updated my question with the more detailed exception message after setting IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII to true.

Comment: Dumb question, in my JWT applications I need to send the key like this 'Bearer [mykey]', are you missing something like this? I.e. the 'Bearer' String in front?

Comment: @rst no, I'm not. The token is properly received by the framework and passed to the validation method. But I found the issue: the delphi token signatures are actually invalid: i was fooled by the jwt.io debugger that will re-sign the payload if you change the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my issue and the problem is my own making.

Short answer: the Delphi tokens are invalid because the code that generates the signature was bugged.

I failed to notice this because JWT.IO will re-generate the token signature every time you change the key so it always said "signature verified" because my test routine was "copy token from VisualStudio, paste it in the JTW debugger, paste the key" which, well, never actually validated the original token.

Answer (score 1):

I got this exact error and spent a long time trying to figure out why.

Here's my formalized answer for anyone still looking for it.

When validating in C# or VB, you have to account for various encodings.

```
Dim symmetricKey = (New Guid(secret)).ToByteArray() 'This array encoding is used by .NET

Dim symmetricKeyUTF8 = (Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret)) 'This is used by Javascript and our Postman example

Dim issuerSigningKeys = New List(Of SecurityKey) From {New SymmetricSecurityKey(symmetricKey), New SymmetricSecurityKey(symmetricKeyUTF8)}
```

Also always check the secret is the same, no matter how obvious it is.